# Chart.js - Adding the values to the labels

Tags: reactjs, arrays, chart.js, label

I want to add values to to my labels just like this: [image]

Here's my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-flower-h9wvqz?file=/App.tsx:1597-1643).

I got 2 problems:

1. My values are undefined when I insert and call this in `generateLabels`:

   let values = chartInstance.data.datasets.data;
2. If I change the value of the variable `values` to [1, 2] per exemple, the graph loads, but the labels on the right vanish.

What I am doing wrong? Thanks.